# Which kind of logic code should be in Components? Which kind of logic code should be in Service?

Tags: angular

In my opinion, it does not matter whether you put a piece of code in `Component` or `Service`. Is that true?

Comment: I think it makes a big difference, esp. as your application grows. For example, as per Angular's tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html : "Multiple components will need access to hero data and we don't want to copy and paste the same code over and over. Instead, we'll create a single reusable data service and learn to inject it in the components that need it."

Comment: Is there an example that you have in mind that you're struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is equivalent to asking: What is the role of Services within the context of the MVC pattern?  In Angular2, the Model is the Object model, specified as member variables of the component class, the Controller is the Component class, and the View is the component template.

Services are responsible for retrieving the Models that the Controller needs to render the view. Hence, Services are view agnostic.

The Controller (or component class) is responsible for taking the Model returned from the Service, and presenting it to the view. In  the case of Angular2, this means saving the Model as a member variable of the component class so that it can be rendered in the View Template.

Application logic belongs in Services. This includes exposing events that subsribers can subscribe to.

The component controller logic should contain logic to subscribe to service events, or call service methods for the purposes of retrieving the model and presenting it to the view (i.e. storing the model as member variables  of the component class).

Answer (score 6):

Any piece of logic that you might need to use multiple times throughout your application should be written as a service.

The logic for how and when to use these services in a view, would be in the component which controls that view.

Based on the [Angular Overview on application architecture](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#components), a **component** should be lean and contain only the logic to control a view.  It should not fetch data from the server or validate user input, but should delegate any such task to a service.

> A component's job is to enable the user experience and nothing more. It mediates between the view (rendered by the template) and the application logic (which often includes some notion of a model). A good component presents properties and methods for data binding. It delegates everything nontrivial to services.

A **service**, on the other hand, is a specific piece of logic that can be reused multiple times throughout your application.  It helps keep your components lean and your application DRY.

> Service is a broad category encompassing any value, function, or feature that your application needs.
>
> Almost anything can be a service. A service is typically a class with a narrow, well-defined purpose. It should do something specific and do it well.

Answer (score 2):

**Component:**

- Should have strictly the logic required to display data to the UI
- DOM events methods(clicks, change, etc ...)
- Methods that change the UI state (Ex: keep a state to display/hide something)
- Life Cycle methods (ngInit, ngDestroy, etc..)

**Service:**

- Should take care of how the data is requested / sent
- Should expose simple methods for the component to receive/send the data
  (component should simply use something like **service.getData()**
  without knowing how this is requested)
- Should have methods to filter the data for the component when needed
  (getUserById, getListByUser, etc...)
- Any other logic that is not strictly UI related can be passed to the
  service (logging, authentication, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

A service a kind of [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), i couldn't explain it simplier.

#### Simple example: Audio Player

Imagine you want to use an Audio Player on your webapp, in order to do so you will have a specific Component (for example in your footer), with all the actions, playlist, current sound etc... But you'll certainly want to interact with it from other Components : imagine a Component which lists some audio files, you will want to put a button next to each in order to play the media or to add it to the current playlist.

Here comes the use of a Service, you'll just have to deport all the actions/playlist/currentSound in your service; it would become the link wetween your audio player and everything that would need to interact with it: play, pause, stop, addToPlaylist, etc...

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Practically it will work, but bad practice especially when sharing logic it should be shared from services instead of modules component (obviously it is cleaner and probably better performance), as angular docs saying components should only present the views.

Answer (score 0):

Think that a service can be reused in multiple components. If you find yourself writing the code in multiple components, you probably need a service.

Also, if you have to do an http request and you want to filter information or do some manipulation, it´s a good idea to separate the concerns and move this logic to an appropriate service. Your component does not need to know the details of how you get the data. Try to abstract your components from the implementation details as much as you can.

Hope it helps!